# Scala Guice - inject with a mixin

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

Is it possible to instantiate the dependency first and then bind it in the module `config` method?

Currently I have the following config:

```
class PersonServiceImpl @Inject()(addressService: AddressService) {
  ...
}

class AppModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule { 

  def configure() {
    bind[PersonService].to[PersonServiceImpl]
    bind[AddressBook].to[AddressBookImpl]
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  def provideAddressService(addressBook: AddressBook): AddressService = {
    new AddressServiceImpl(addressBook) with SecureAddressView
  }

}
```

... which works fine. What I want to do now is to move the instantiation of the `AddressServiceImpl` into a separate module. So, the problem is that in order to create an instance of `AddressServiceImpl` I need Guice to inject the `addressBook` parameter for me, but I also want to create the instance myself so I can mix SecureAddressView in:

```
class AddressModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule { 

  def configure() {
    bind[AddressService].to[AddressServiceImpl]
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  def provideAddressService(addressBook: AddressBook): AddressService = {
    new AddressServiceImpl(addressBook) with SecureAddressView
  }

}
```

This fails, though, as Guice comes back complaining about the `provideAddressService` method. It basically says that `A binding to AddressService was already configured` and points to the `bind[AddressService].to[AddressServiceImpl]` line in the `configure` method.

Any idea how to create an instance and mix in a trait while still delegating the resolution of downstream parameter dependencies to Guice?

Comment: Guice will not allow defining 2 methods to create the same interface. I'm not a Scala developer so I won't write this as an answer, but what you need are [Binding Annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). Use either `@Named("secure")` for your AddressService with SecureAddressView and let the binding in the configure method be used wherever you don't indicate `@Named`. You could also create your own `@SecureAddress` annotation to use instead if you don't like `@Named("secure")`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, quite an obvious one but I was misled by the fact that I had to override the `configure` method. So, all I had to do is provide a dummy implementation for `configure`.

```
class AddressModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule { 

  override def configure(): Unit = ()

  @Provides @Singleton
  def provideAddressService(addressBook: AddressBook): AddressService = {
    new AddressServiceImpl(addressBook) with SecureAddressView
  }

}
```

Although this still looks quite dodgy as I have to provide explicitly all the parameters to the AddressService constructor. There must be a more elegant way of mixin traits. Or maybe not...